# Assert is typeguard

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Can anybody explain to me why in the console log the `notUser` has a type

```
const notUser: {
    items: any[];
} & User
```

I expect it to be `User`

```js
interface User {
  id: string
}
function assVal (obj:any): asserts obj is User {
  if(!('id' in obj && typeof obj.id === 'string')) throw new Error()
}

const notUser = {items: []}

assVal(notUser)

console.log(notUser)
```

as same as in this example:

```js
interface User {
  id: string
}
function isUser (obj:any): obj is User {
  return 'id' in obj && typeof obj.id === 'string'
}

const notUser = {items: []}

if(isUser(notUser)) {
  console.log(notUser)
}
```

In if block the `notUser` has a type

```
const notUser: {
    items: any[];
} & User
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `const notUser` is <s>declared</s> inferred to have the type `{ items: any[]; }` due to its declaration. That means it could hold any object that has [*at least*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing) has an `.items` array property. It may also have other properties, like an `.id` string, TypeScript doesn't know or care here, those would still be compatible.

The type guard [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of the variable, since it is (in the guarded scope) **also** known to be a `User`. But that doesn't mean it looses its original type, rather, it has both.

Comment: That makes sense, but let me show you one more example. Here in playground, you can see I have the union of interfaces and it makes the intersection inside: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMumFKAOa4C+uoksiKAwgBZxSLM74FkAV0xQQcALYQyFKiFoMYQkAjDAA9iELoMWABTqARgCsScEAE8AlGSPHtaUfwJQIYIWOQByYl8Ja7ZAAyIOQwCwAHCHUYZDsAOmJkAF5U71kaL3pcXARNCmQQdTBdKDJS5AAfZE5uXixknBFocSkyLy8GRhg9YB1RPSKS0SsrZ2Q8kHR1ABsIeJn1akHi0qtsoA

Comment: @programmer What do you mean by "*it makes the intersection inside*"?

Comment: It makes it `const notUser: Character & User`

Comment: @programmer That's because in that example, `notUser` has the type `Character` due to [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) from the initialisation. The type guard then further narrows this down to "also `User`", just like in your original example.

Comment: @programmer To see the union narrowed down to one of its member types, have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMumFKAOa4C+uoksiKAwgBZxSLM74FkAV0xQQcALYQyFKiFoMYQkAjDAA9iELoMWABTqARgCsScEAE8AlGSPHtaUfwJQIYIWOQByYl8Ja7ZAAyIOQwCwAHCHUYZDsAOmJkAF5U71kaL3pcXCUVNU1kCAAPSQiAGwg9EHUwXSgyeuQAH2RObl5oK2dCWL1gHVFq2vqrbrxBZARNdHVK+PL1amG60SsBBgYgA

Comment: @programmer If the narrowed type is not a member of the union, you get the intersection with the union itself: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMumFKAOa4C+uoksiKAwgBZxSLM77IArpigg4AWwhkKVELQZNo8JMgCCCBAHtB4fgQA2m6qGmUa9XDB0IwwTSELoMWABSaARgCsScEAE8ASjIPT0c0ET1kKAgwQVFkAHJiBMIHEOQAMgzkMD8ABwhNGGQQgDpiZABeasSZGgSLS2tbe2QIAA8JPP0IFxBNMGcoMnUtHTBkAB9kTm5eaADI4GKXYCcRPoGhgMW8AgItEHRNHtLDak3BkQCBBgYgA